# Silverlight toolkit for WP7, DatePicker\TimePicker fontsize pro­blem

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, datepicker, font-size, toolkit

I have following problem with TimePicker \ DatePicker from Silverlight Toolkit for WP7. I don't know how to change the font size in TextBox inside picker:

[image]

FontSize property:

```
<toolkit:DatePicker FontSize="30" Foreground="Black"  Header="tas" Name="dpiker"/>
```

changes only Header font size

[image]

Although **FontFamily** or **FontWeight** applies to both Header and TextBox. How to change FontSize in TextBox?

[Here is the same question o silverlight forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/silverlightcontrols/thread/55b517d5-99b0-4c01-8f82-983baa201bb0/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because in their default styles, the font size is not set via TemplateBinding. See the **** part, that should do the trick. :)

```
    <Style TargetType="toolkit:DatePicker">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="PickerPageUri" Value="/Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit;component/DateTimePickers/DatePickerPage.xaml"/>
        <Setter Property="ValueStringFormat" Value="{}{0:d}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="toolkit:DatePicker">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneSubtleBrush}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="12,0,12,-4"/>
                        <Button x:Name="DateTimeButton" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Content="{TemplateBinding ValueString}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Height="72" **FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"**/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Had to exclude PickerPageUri property then it works as expected on Windows Phone 8 SDK + Windows Phone Toolkit 4.2013 to set font size. There's another sample in https://windowsphone.svn.wordpress.org/trunk/WordPress/App.xaml which has template setter for TimePicker also.

Answer (score 0):

Based on wordpress link from noxo this worked well for me :

```
    <Style x:Key="DatePickerStyle1" TargetType="toolkit:DatePicker" BasedOn="{StaticResource DateTimePickerStyles}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="toolkit:DatePicker">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneSubtleBrush}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="12,0,12,-4"/>
                        <Button x:Name="DateTimeButton" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Content="{TemplateBinding ValueString}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Height="Auto" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```